# Android start layout with current orientation, after that disable rotation

Tags: android, configuration, orientation, landscape, portrait

I want to make possible to use an activity in landscape / portrait. The activity starts with the layout for the current orientation (that means before starting the activity). After that it has to stick to it, and not react to orientation change.

I tried putting

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

in the manifest of the activity, and overriding

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

to do nothing (tried commenting the super call too, but this lead to exception)
but this has not the effect disabling the rotation change - the change is processed and the layout reconstructed, it just doesn't use the correct one.

And I can't use

```
android:screenOrientation
```

Because it seems I have to specify only one mode for always, and that's not what I need either.
And anyways, if I specify something there, the activity gets reconstructed when rotating. 
Tried with

```
android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
```

that doesn't do anything

Here there's a lock of current orientation with code
    http://www.samcoles.co.uk/mobile/android-lock-and-unlock-screen-orientation/

But it achieves the same effect as specifying orientation in XML (keeps layout but reconstructs the activity). It's a bit nearer to what I want (keeps orientation from start), but reconstructs the activity and I don't want it to react at all.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I could not get the landscape orientation to stick. It just disabled my landscaping xml from being chosen, using `android:configChanges="orientation" ` plus overriding `onConfigurationChanged` as you show, had this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android:configChanges="orientation" doesn't work on the emulator at all, but it works fine on devices.

Comment: Could be, I'm using the emulator. Can't test on any device right now.

Comment: I've had the same issue. it didn't work for the emulator, but I've tried on several phones and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    newConfig.orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: This works keeping the layout, but the activity is reconstructed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to onCreate

```
if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);}
        else {setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);}
```